# Show whether a Python module is loaded from bytecode

Tags: python, bytecode, hy

I'm trying to debug [Hy](https://github.com/hylang/hy)'s use of bytecode. In particular, each time a module is imported, I want to see the path it was actually imported from, whether source or bytecode. Under the hood, Hy manages modules with `importlib`. It doesn't explicitly read or write bytecode; that's taken care of by `importlib.machinery.SourceFileLoader`. So it looks like what I want to do is monkey-patch Python's importing system to print the import path each time an import happens. How can I do that? I should be able to figure out how to do it for Hy once I understand how to do it for Python.

Comment: In Python source code, you can access a module's source file through its `__file__` attribute.  I'm not an expert on Python bytecode, but I see no reason you couldn't work out how to print that through bytecode, and post-process your generated bytecode files to do that after every import.

Comment: I may be wrong, but I believe all python is loaded from bytecode.  I think you want to ask if it was loaded from cached bytecode, or if the bytecode was generated from a source file.

Comment: @dwysocki Generally, `__file__` points to the source file, even if the module was loaded from bytecode. @monkut The question is not to figure whether a given bytecode file came from a source file, but whether a given `import` read from source or from bytecode.

Comment: @Kodiologist again, `import` doesn't really read directly from the source, the source is found, and if there is a pre-cached bytecode file, it just uses it, otherwise, it creates the bytecode from the source code. But the module/code is fundamentally created from the bytecode always. I don't think any record is kept of whether or not a pre-cached bytecode file is used or not, but perhaps someone knows something, almost certainly some implementation detail

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga My concern is what file is read and not whether bytecode is made as an intermediate step. I don't think there's some record of what was done that's left over, either, which is why I expect to need to monkey-patch the import code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way that does not involve coding, is to start Python with two(!) verbose flags:

```
python -vv myscript.py
```

you'll get a lot of output, including all the import statements and all the files Python tries to access in order to load the module. In this example I have a simple python script that does `import json`:

```
lots of output!
[...]
# trying /tmp/json.cpython-310-x86_64-linux-gnu.so                                                                                                                                              
# trying /tmp/json.abi3.so                                                                                                                                                                      
# trying /tmp/json.so                                                                                                                                                                           
# trying /tmp/json.py                                                                                                                                                                           
# trying /tmp/json.pyc                                                                                                                                                                          
# /usr/lib/python3.10/json/__pycache__/__init__.cpython-310.pyc matches /usr/lib/python3.10/json/__init__.py                                                                                    
# code object from '/usr/lib/python3.10/json/__pycache__/__init__.cpython-310.pyc' 
[...]
```

Alternatively but more complex: you could change the `import` statement itself. For that, you can overwrite [`__import__`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#import__), which is invoked by the `import` statement itself. This way you could print out all the files `import` actually opens.

Comment: The output is of `-vv` is massive, but when I do `python -vv myscript.py |& less` and search for the module name, I can find messages like the above that say whether a bytecode file is created or read from.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a good option would be to dynamically patch  `importlib.machinery.SourceFileLoader(fullname, path)` and `importlib.machinery.SourcelessFileLoader(fullname, path)` to each print or write to a variable (a) the calling method and (b) the argument passed to the function.

If all you need to do is:

> I want to see the path it was actually imported from, whether source or bytecode

And you don't need the import to "work properly", perhaps you can do a modified version of something like [this](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/monkeypatch.html#monkeypatching-returned-objects-building-mock-classes). For example, I quickly modified their sample code to get this, I have not tested it so it may not work exactly, but it should get you on the right track:

```py
# custom class to be the mock return value
class MockSourceLoader:

    # mock SourceFileLoader method always returns that the module was loaded from source and its path

    def SourceFileLoader(fullname, path):
        return {"load type": "source", "fullname": fullname, "path": path}

def check_how_imported(monkeypatch):

    # Any arguments may be passed and mock_get() will always return our
    # mocked object
    def mock_get(*args, **kwargs):
        return MockSourceLoader

    # apply the monkeypatch
    monkeypatch.setattr(importlib.machinery, SourceFileLoader, SourceFileLoader)
```

You would of course provide a similar mock for Sourceless file loading for `SourcelessFileLoader`

For reference:

- [https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#:~:text=importlib.machinery.SourceFileLoader(fullname%2C%20path)%C2%B6](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#:%7E:text=importlib.machinery.SourceFileLoader(fullname%2C%20path)%C2%B6)
- [https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#:~:text=importlib.machinery.SourcelessFileLoader(fullname%2C%20path)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#:%7E:text=importlib.machinery.SourcelessFileLoader(fullname%2C%20path))